# Reading event logs and acting when specific event is not present

Tags: c#

I have a small application which is basically a `FileSystemWatcher` which performs some operations when a file is updated.

What I need it to do is query the event logs and check whether a specific event fired.

To achieve this I created the `EventLogHelper` class:

```
class EventLogHelper
{
    private readonly int Timespan; 
    private readonly string PcName;
    private readonly string Filter;

    public EventLogHelper()
    {
        Timespan = 30000;
        PcName = Environment.MachineName;
        Filter = $"*[System[(EventID='5061' or EventID='5058') and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= {Timespan}]]]";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the event logs for remote pc and returns true if any of the events we are interested in fired. 
    /// This will try checking 30 times (or until the event is found) with a 1 second wait after each check. 
    /// </summary>
    public bool CheckEvents()
    {
        var query = BuildQuery(PcName, Filter);

        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            var logs = QueryEvents(query);
            var events = ReadLogs(logs);

            if (events > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds an EventLogQuery for the given pcname and filter. This user needs to be in the Event Log Readers security group. 
    /// </summary>
    private static EventLogQuery BuildQuery(string pcName, string filter)
    {
        var session = new EventLogSession();
        using (var pw = GetPassword())
        {
            session = new EventLogSession(
            pcName,
            "DOMAIN",
            "SystemAccount",
            pw,
            SessionAuthentication.Default);
        }

        return new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, filter)
            { Session = session };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute the given EventLogQuery
    /// </summary>
    private static EventLogReader QueryEvents(EventLogQuery query)
    {
        try
        {
            return new EventLogReader(query);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Email.Send($"Error occured when instantiating a new EventLogReader \n\n Exception: {ex.Message} \n\n");
            Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
        }

        return new EventLogReader(query);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read the given EventLogReader and return the amount of events that match the IDs we are looking for
    /// </summary>
    private static int ReadLogs(EventLogReader logReader)
    {
        var count5058 = 0;
        var count5061 = 0;
        EventRecord entry;

        while ((entry = logReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
        {
            if (entry.Id == 5058)
            {
                count5058++;
            }
            else
            {
                count5061++;
            }
        }

        return count5058 + count5061;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Return the password stored in an encrypted bytearray. 
    /// </summary>
    private static SecureString GetPassword()
    {
        byte[] data = { 14, 105, 212, 35, 167, 212, 91, 78, 1, 216, 136, 25, 80, 60, 164, 160 };
        var crypto = new SimpleAES();
        var outval = crypto.Decrypt(data);

        var ss = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in outval)
        {
            ss.AppendChar(c);
        }

        return ss;
    }
```

---

I am fairly happy with this class and the method in general, as I can call it like so in my event handler (when the file gets updated):

```
var eventHelper = new EventLogHelper();
var result = eventHelper.CheckEvents();

if (!result)
{
    // The event didn't fire - we need to act!
}
```

However there are a couple of things which I am not sure about, for example my pattern in `CheckEvents` seems reasonable as I only call `BuildQuery` once, but do I really need to call `QueryEvents` on every iteration?

---

I also have concerns about the `QueryEvents` method itself, where I have the same return statement twice. This was originally written as:

```
private static EventLogReader QueryEvents(EventLogQuery query)
{
    return new EventLogReader(query);
}
```

But this can throw an `Unauthorised Access` error, so I need to handle that. Is there a better way of writing this statement where I don't need to write the return statement twice?

I thought about adding `EventLogReader` as a property, but then I don't know how to pass in the `eventQuery` after the reader has already been initialised.

Comment: Have you actually run this? `QueryEvents()` will terminate the application every time it's called.

Comment: @eurotrash Sorry about that - the finally block was meant to be removed, I have updated my question

Comment: @eurotrash the idea with that was that since the application will exit in the `catch` due to `Environment.Exit`, the final `return` will never be called (which makes me feel that it is redundant) - but the method has to return something!

Comment: Have you tried that now after the change? I think VS should allow you to remove that second return now.

Comment: @eurotrash I am not at that pc any more, but VS does not allow this: `static int Test()
        {
            try
            {
                var asd = 5; 
                return asd;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
            }
        }` with a `Not all code paths return a value` error

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: @Mast thanks for the information - I will put my edits in a new answer

Comment: I do not understand this "But this can throw an Unauthorised Access error, so I need to handle that. Is there a better way of writing this statement where I don't need to write the return statement twice?" How does double return helps you in this case ? Doesn't the second return throw an exception ?

Comment: @Disappointed No, because the application has already either exited, or the method has returned by that point. The reason why I included it is because VS complains that the method has no return value if I leave it out - I feel like this is most likely a design issue!

Comment: @chicks this question is not about event-handlig but about the event-log which is something entirely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `ReadLogs` is a little ridiculous

> ```
> private static int ReadLogs(EventLogReader logReader)
> {
>     var count5058 = 0;
>     var count5061 = 0;
>     EventRecord entry;
>
>     while ((entry = logReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
>     {
>         if (entry.Id == 5058)
>         {
>             count5058++;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             count5061++;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return count5058 + count5061;
> }
> ```

Isn't it the same as the following ?!

```
private static int ReadLogs(EventLogReader logReader)
{
    var count = 0;
    EventRecord entry;

    while ((entry = logReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
    {
       count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right - I updated my code to reflect what I was actually trying to do. You see I need both events to fire, so without checking the ID I risk count returning as 2 where its just the same ID firing twice (this is quite common in this scenario) thank you for spotting that!¬

Answer (score 2):

This code here is a little redundant

> ```
> private static EventLogQuery BuildQuery(string pcName, string filter)
> {
>     var session = new EventLogSession();
>     using (var pw = GetPassword())
>     {
>         session = new EventLogSession(
>         pcName,
>         "DOMAIN",
>         "SystemAccount",
>         pw,
>         SessionAuthentication.Default);
>     }
>
>     return new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, filter)
>         { Session = session };
> }
> ```

you create a new `EventLogSession` twice when you only need to do that once, doing this you will have to return from inside the using statement, but that is perfectly okay.

You should also indent the parameters that you are passing into the constructor method, so that you can see that these are not new commands inside the using statement.

```
private static EventLogQuery BuildQuery(string pcName, string filter)
{
    using (var pw = GetPassword())
    {
        var session = new EventLogSession(
            pcName,
            "DOMAIN",
            "SystemAccount",
            pw,
            SessionAuthentication.Default);
        return new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, filter)
            { Session = session };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is redundant too:

> ```
> private static EventLogReader QueryEvents(EventLogQuery query)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         return new EventLogReader(query);
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         Email.Send($"Error occured when instantiating a new EventLogReader \n\n Exception: {ex.Message} \n\n");
>         Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
>     }
>
>     return new EventLogReader(query);
> }
> ```

the last line will never be reached so you may just return a `null` in the `catch` to satisfy the compiler.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to know! I foolishly assumed that because some types can't be returned as `null` that this was the same for all - but it does work in this case.

Comment: @Bassie the `null` works only with reference types this is with everything that is a class see [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

To add to what others have said:

Use constants!

```
private readonly int Timespan;
```

This is only set in the constructor you can just do:

```
private const int Timespan = 30000;
```